# Is the expression "What is the time on your side?" appropriate?

Tags: expressions, formality, email

I want to inform place A, where I have applied for a job, that I have received a job offer from place B. My attempt is "*[...] I take this opportunity to let you know that I have received an offer from place B. I have few days to decide and I was wondering **what is the time on your side***"

Question: is the expression "what is the time on your side" appropriate to investigate whether place A has already taken a decision or whether it could consider to take a decision on my application quicker (without putting too much pressure)? If it is not, which expression would you suggest?

Comment: This sounds like writing advice, which isn't a good fit for this site. "What is the time on your side" doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: Maybe you mean "time frame" on your end. It is a little more idiomatic, but are they native speakers to understand idiomatic English...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would interpret "what is the time on your side" as asking what time (as in, time on the clock) it is for me - for example, if I were talking to someone in a different time zone.

You might want to ask:
"What is your timeline for making a decision on my application?"

Or, most simply:
"When will you make a decision on my application?"

Also, consider simplifying your language throughout this communication. "Taking the opportunity to let you know" is needlessly wordy. In general, fewer words = clearer communication.

How about this:

*Dear Manager At Place A, I've received a compelling offer from another company. I'm still interested in your position because I think it's a great fit with my skills and experience, but I must reply to this offer by Friday. When do you expect to make a decision on the position?*